# Finding undocumented tags?

Tags: support, tags

While browsing around, I noticed that the [[panasonic-lumix](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panasonic-lumix)] tag was both reasonably well used (18 questions anyway) and undocumented. I've remedied the undocumented part, but is there an easy way to find the most used undocumented tags on photo.SE?

Comment: Hmmm... I've just seen [the post about data.SE](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/937/useful-data-stackexchange-com-queries-for-regular-users-of-the-site), which I wasn't aware of. I'll see if I can get this data that way if there isn't a more direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

**[Tags missing a tag wiki or tag excerpt, sorted by use](http://data.stackexchange.com/photography/query/157704/tags-missing-a-tag-wiki-or-tag-excerpt-sorted-by-use)**

Comment: Note that "camera" is currently at the top, but it leads nowhere since we killed that tag just the other day. The data refreshes weekly....

Comment: Great stuff - thanks :-) Now to document some of them...